Can I wire an AC/AC SSR input control pins in series with a load?
Is there a way for an AC/AC SSR to trigger when current flows between its input contacts?
I mean, instead of wiring N and L from the outlet directly into its input contacts (with a switch,) I’d like it to be wired in series with an input-load, to sense when this load was turned on, and then it would close the contacts on the SSR’s output pins, allowing an AC load on the output to be turned on.
I saw some current switches and some current detector modules, but often they require some extra VCC input to work. I prefer a simple solution, with fewer extra components due to lack of space in my control box.

The devil will be in the details of your application.

If you want switch AC big load with AC small value, it is possible if your SSR based on triac.

Unlikely unless your load is a couple of mA and doesn't fluctuate.


Is there a way for an AC/AC SSR to trigger when current flows between
it’s input contacts?

I think this should work: -

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Good luck.
EDIT: as per @transistor's observation, if the triac needs to switch on another load then use the above circuit except rewire the triac terminals to control that load directly and short out R2: -


I think the OP wants to switch on a different load. e.g., Switch on the dust extract fan when the saw is switched on.

@Transistor you may be correct. I didn't read it that way but I can see how it might be true.

@Transistor, that's correct. Different loads... More details added in the question!

@Andyaka I added more info on my SSR module... Do you think this very module can be "modded" to be able to do what the circuit you proposed does?

@Rodrigo that's not what we do here so I have rolled your question back to how it was when two answers were made. Please don't move the goalposts on this question; instead, raise a new post and close this session down in the normal way. Raising a new post allows many more folk in to make an answer and, is therefore advantageous to you.

@Andyaka Ok! Will do it! Thanks for the advice!

@Rodrigo please let me know when you make that post and, don't forget to include a link back to this (your) original post.

@Andyaka Just posted: here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/708950/can-i-modify-this-ac-ac-ssr-module-to-allow-it-be-connected-in-series-with-a-loa


Basic SSR. Image source: LEDnique.
Most SSRs are a beefed up version of the opto-TRIAC pictured above. The trigger needs about 10 to 20 mA to power the LED to turn on the TRIAC.
You seem to be thinking of trying to wire the opto side of the SSR (basically the LED) in series with your load to use the SSR as a current sensing relay. You might be able to get this to work if:

The SSR's trigger circuit will accept AC.
The load draws 10 to 20 mA. (Check the datasheet for the SSR.)
The opto circuit only drops a few volts.

Generally, "no" is the answer.
