Can I modify this AC/AC SSR module to allow it be connected in series with a load at its control pins?
This is a follow-up to my question at: Can I wire an AC/AC SSR input control pins in series with a load?
I have this AC/AC SSR module (Fotek SSR-10AA - schematics and pictures added) and I'd like to know if it's possible to modify it to be able to connect a load in series with its input pins, and not "pure" 127V at the SSR's input. So when the load at the input pin is turned on, the SSR would allow current to flow and turn on a different load at its output pins.
My "input" load at 127V draws at max 500mA.
The load the will be turned on at the output, at 127V draws only 50mA.
I saw some current switches and some current detector modules, but often they require some extra VCC input to work. I prefer a simple solution, if possible, to modify the very SSR I own.
My SSR best-bet schematics: (I couldn't find the exact one as they're clones of clones of clones.) My module has a diode bridge, and not four separate diodes, for instance. My module's TRIAC is the BTA 24.

My SSR internal pictures. Top of each picture is the INPUT part.


Edit 1:
My goal is:
When Device 1 (my input device)  is turned on by pressing its on/off switch (which I have only access to the contacts on the AC power cord and not to the internal contacts of its power switch) I need that  Device 2 be automatically turned on (there’s no on/off switch in this other device).
When device 1 is turned off (by pressing its on/off switch) , the device 2 has to be automatically disconnected from its AC supply.

Why can't you just put the input control pins directly across the load. That will establish that your load is turned on without having to detect the flow of current into it?

I wouldn't be surprised if the output TRIAC wouldn't stay on during the half-cycle if the load is only 50 mA.

@Andyaka I don't have access to the on/off switch pins.. I only have access to the power cord of the load...

@Transistor actually the output load is a AC/DC converter, from 127 AC to 24VDC. From this 24VDC there's 250mA current draw on the load attached to the AC/DC converter.

@Rodrigo do you mean the load you wish to switch?

The current on the DC side of your converter is irrelevant. The TRIAC will respond to the AC input draw and since that's a switching regulator with a rectifier and smoothing capacitor it will only draw current at the peak of the AC. I think you should edit your question and add a note explaining what is the real problem you're trying to solve. It seems that you are chasing a solution that may not be the best approach.

@Transistor edited the question to try to make it more clear. The input load varies from 100 to 500mA. The output load is the one at 50mA at 127V

@Andyaka I mean.. the load I want to be checked if it's on or off, the "input" load. Although there's a swtich, I can't access it's terminals... I only have access to it's power cable. Its case can't be opened..

@Rodrigo if you have access to its power cable maybe you could break open that cable and use the SSR as intended. Surely this must be easier than trying to rework the SSR.

@Andyaka I can mess with the power cable, cut it.. but how will it be done? Won't it then be like wiring the SSR directly to the both outlet contacts? Won't it be in parallel to my device? Then it'll be always on, won't it?

Yes it will and, it will deactivate when the switch goes open circuit

@Andyaka I still don't get it... Could you draw this? It only makes sense to me if I wire the device at the input of the ssr in series with it. Check these falstad links to see how I'm seeing it: https://tinyurl.com/2xjob6cw and this one: https://tinyurl.com/22gwtsch

SSR input L and N connections wire in parallel with the switched device (the thing you wish to monitor). When that switched device becomes activated (by the switch), then the triac in your SSR also becomes activated and can control another load.

@Andyaka My device also needs to be connected to L and N, the same way the SSR inputs, right (in parallel)? The thing is N and L always have voltage in it, regardless the position of the device's switch. Internally, the switch turns on and off the device's electronics, but don't cut voltage on it's  outside AC plug. So at the plug, where I have access, there's always voltage in it. So the SSR will always be on, even If the device if off...

I think you need to produce a circuit of what you have. I've tried to understand what you have and clearly, I'm failing so, please add a schematic of what you have and draw some markers on it where you want the external load controlled. Also put markers on it showing what wiring you have access to.

@andyaka I did a circuit diagram. The SSR part is just for info, no real values in it... and it's wired  ON all the time.. I need it to be "wired" only when the input load is on...  See if you can understand what I need now.... Check the diagram here: https://ibb.co/8Ds7YBG

Try to find a current transformer, or current sensor, that fits in your application. These devices will not have voltage drop, and will not influence in the "input load".
Primary should be rated  > 500 mA, and for secondary you need 20 mA or more to switch on the opto coupler of the SSR. The secondary should be rectified and filter, and a zener (not easy to find high current) or shunt regulator is necessary to limit voltage (the lower voltage you can design, better for the current transformer). Check if transformer/sensor can supply that voltage, because usually are limited.
See proposal with TL 431 (sink current 100 mA).


My suggestion is to use the existing SSR (without modification) and wire it to the input load (see the purple wires).


That's the catch.. I don't have access to that PIN of the switch. it's internal to the case and the case can't be opened...  So I only have access to the N and L external terminals, where the AC plug is connected... That's why I wanted to monitor the current in some way...
